# Как изменить и записать текст в системный конфиг в android?

Tags: android, java

Пишу небольшой твикер для мобилы, надо, чтоб он открывал и редактировал файлик build.prop, но что-то у меня не выходит... В манифесте есть пермишн только на изменение файлов на флешке. Как реализовать? При условии что аппарат рутованный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы отредактировать файл build.prop, который лежит в папке /system, нужно монтировать файловую систему с правами на запись

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

При условии, что у приложения **действительно** есть права, необходимые для изменения системных файлов, можно сделать также из приложения

```
os.writeBytes("mount -o remount rw /system/\n");
```

Еще одна опция - использовать [roottools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/wiki/RootTools).

```
RootTools.remount("/system/", "rw");
```

Comment: спасибо, а в манифест что добавлять надо?

Comment: делаю открытие файла с RootTools, система ругается что "File system/build.prop contains a path separator"